# Get rid the slash in URL (ex. something.com/dogs)

Tags: dns, slash

I recently purchased the domain name simply.do. I want to use it as a URL shortening service, but I don't like have to do simply.do/something. Can I remove the slash or replace it with a difference symbol?

If this helps, I am using a server running Nginx and I will not switch to Apache.

Thanks!

I would also appreciate any feedback on the domain name. I was hoping to sell simply.do/insurance, simply.do/religion, etc. to various companies. Do you think there is a way I could sell these parts on an auction website? Thanks!

Comment: The slash is required as part of URL syntax.

Comment: You can use `dogs.something.com` i.e. sub domain instead of slash

Comment: Would it be possible to redirect people if I did simply.do?insurance? Is there any other kind of symbol I could use in the URL to redirect people besides a slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know how the HTTP protocol works here, to better understand what you are doing. If you want to sell the URLs, you need a basic URI handler for /insurance, or /religion. You can also sell insurance.simply.do, If you want to, thru' DNSes and default VirtualHost handlers.

This answer is irrespective of the server used.

Comment: Would it be possible to redirect people if I did simply.do?insurance? Is there any other kind of symbol I could use in the URL to redirect people besides a slash?

Comment: @jbenes: You must have at least one slash after the host name. After that, you can use query part (delimited by `?`) to do redirection.

Answer (score 2):

When you visit `simply.do`, that refers to `simply.do/index.php` (if you use php in background).

So, you can use it as query, for eg, simply.do?insurance will lead to some long url like `://a-long-domain-name/a-long-list-of-directories`.

Use server script to get the value after `?` mark so that if someone visite `simply.do?insurance`, it will be like `simply.do/index.php?insurance`. It works with all browsers.

You can obtain the value from the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` OR `$_GET[]` array, check if the query string: 'insurance' is in your db or not. If yes, redirect the user to required site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove/replace the `/` right after `simply.do` since it delimits the host and the path in the URI.